# How to write this query in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 ,how to write this query?

There are two tables,`user` and `articles`,they have a one-to-many relationship.

I want to query users according to these conditions:
1、Show users who have articles,not show users who have not articles.
2、Articles contain two types,published and not published, "1" indicates published,show published articles ,not show articles which not published.
3、30 users are shown per page.

Like this, it's not right ,how to modify it?

HomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('articles')->where('is_published','=',1)->paginate(30);
    return view('index', compact('users'));
}
```

User:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, HasRoleAndPermissionContract

{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, HasRoleAndPermission;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }

}
```

Article:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    //edit-1:         
    //Scope a query to only include status=1.
    public function scopeStatus($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status',1);
    }

}
```

edit:
@SSuhat @RamilAmr Thanks! If there is a Local Scope in Model "Article",how to modify the answer:

```
$query = User::with(['articles' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('is_published', 1);
            }])
         ->has('articles') //<<<<<<<<<
         ->paginate(30);
return $query;
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not right"? Can you post your Eloquent Models it would be a great help!

Comment: @JohnRoca  Thansk.I have posted  Eloquent Models.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$query = User::with(['articles' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('is_published', 1);
            }])->paginate(30);
return $query;
```

Comment: Thanks,if the user has not any articles,the user will not be shown,how to filter?

Answer (score 1):

> if the user has not any articles,the user will not be shown,how to filter?

Try this code:

```
$query = User::with(['articles' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('is_published', 1);
            }])
         ->has('articles') //<<<<<<<<<
         ->paginate(30);
return $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = User::with('articles')->wherehas('articles', function ($q) {
            $q->where('is_published', 1);
        })->paginate(30);
return $query;
```

I hope this helps you.